# Java: How to return the only element in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a Robot Maze where the robot finds the target without crashing into walls. I have commented my code thoroughly so hopefully it'll be understandable.

At the dead end and corridor, there will be only one passage in the `passageDirections` `ArrayList`. How do I return this one and only direction?

Any help is appreciated :)

PS: I am a beginner programmer, still learning so explain your answer as if you were to explain it to a three year old :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `passageDirections.get(0)`, which will return the first element in the list.
Since (I hope that) you guarantee there is a single element in the list, that solves your issue.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Comment: such a simple solution! No clue how I missed that haha. The thing is, it compile fine, however it can't run it for some reason :(

Comment: @codeav3 What do you mean by  "*...can't run it for some reason*"? In most cases reasons are explicitly mentioned in errors messages :)

Comment: @pshemo its an error that gets repeated continuously whilst the program runs. The robot doesn't move. `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`...`Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`...

Comment: @codeav3 So you got the reason: size of used collection is 0, which means that there are no elements in it, so you can't `get` any element (since there is none).

Comment: @pshemo I don't see how that's possible :( Do you mind reviewing my code?

Comment: @codeav3 Simplest way to rest it would be by running debugger, but this would require having all related classes used in your code but I don't have `uk.ac.warwick.dcs.maze.logic.IRobot` class.

Comment: @pshemo maybe i could run a debugger? do you recommend any?

Comment: @codeav3 Each IDE like Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ has its own debugger. Use the one you want.

Comment: @codeav3: shoot, even sprinkling `System.out.println(...)` statements throughout your program to query the state of its variables as it runs can help with debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the size before calling to prevent IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
if (passageDirections.size() > 0)
  passageDirections.get(0)
```

Comment: This does not prevent the `NullPointerException`, it prevent the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. But it is still a good idea to check first.